# What is this timestamp format: 090912154113?

Tags: php, date, format, timestamp

What kind of timestamp is this :

```
090912154113
```

more :

```
082712032309
122711190042
091112090931
```

it looks like the regular unix time but with different format, what is it and how to do it using php ?

Comment: seems to be a unixtime... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like 9th September 2012 at 3(15 in 24hr format):41 and 13 seconds (mmddyyhhmmss).
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php, mdyHis using php formatting.

Comment: how did u convert it, using php ?.. and btw the first one (ddmmyyhhmmss) seemed more legit to me

Comment: @Osa - The 1st one is using generic characters (psuedo-code), the 2nd is using the php date formatting routine referenced by the link.

Answer (score -1):

it seems to be:  MMDDYYHHmmSS.

Comment: it starts with `mmdd` and not the other way around, because there's no month '27'.