# What do Gawker media uses as timestamp format?

Tags: date, rss, timestamp, timestamp-analysis

I'm trying to build a [rss bridge](https://github.com/sebsauvage/rss-bridge) to obtain all gawker press articles in my rss reader (as their rss streams only show excerpts from these articles).

Examining a page with Firebug, I've found out there is a timestamp associated with each article, which is good.

However, when feeding an online timestamp converter with those, I find the returned date is not correct. As an example, this article [Unified Remote Gets iOS App, Mac Server for Cross-Platform Control](http://lifehacker.com/unified-remote-gets-ios-app-mac-server-for-cross-platf-1553595268) has as timestamp `1396017000991` which a javascript associates with 3/28/14 7:30am.

Could it be [like in another PHP question MMDDYYhhmmss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769165/what-is-this-timestamp-format-090912154113) ? Well, no, as it would be month 13 day 96 year 01.

So, what is used format ? And how can I parse it to a meaningful UNIX timestamp ?

**[EDIT 1]** According to [FMDiff](http://fmdiff.com/fm/timestamp.html), this timestamp is none of

- UNIX Decimal
- MAC Decimal
- FM Dec Decimal (whatever it is)

**[EDIT 2]]** Initial answer appeared quite good, but my tests using [PHP Repl](http://phpepl.cloudcontrolled.com/) revealed it was not so clear :

```
$epoch = 1396018800571;
echo date('r', $epoch);
```

Echoes "Fri, 29 Jan 46208 01:09:31 +0100" (not good)

Obviously, using $epoch/1000 work in that case, but when i try to inject this date in my timestamp, it results in wrong date.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Could you elaborate on what wrong date you're getting? All of the timestamps in your question seem to come out to recent dates when divided by 1000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a [Javascript timestamp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now), the number of milliseconds since the beginning of the epoch. Dividing by 1000 should give you the UNIX timestamp. See PHP code below.

```
function js_to_unix_timestamp($jsTimestamp){
  return $jsTimestamp/1000; 
}

$timestamp = 1396017000991; //Expect 3/28/14 7:30am

echo date('r', js_to_unix_timestamp($timestamp));
//Actual Fri, 28 Mar 2014 15:30:00 +0100
//Correct to within some UTC offset

$timestamp = 1396018800571; //Given in question
echo date('r', js_to_unix_timestamp($timestamp));
//Actual Fri, 28 Mar 2014 16:00:00 +0100 
//Correct?

$timestamp = 1396032315623; //Current time given by Date.now() in javascript
echo date('r', js_to_unix_timestamp($timestamp));
//Actual Fri, 28 Mar 2014 19:45:15 +0100
//Correct
```

Comment: Good job : I copy/pasted your function, and it works correctly. Thanks.